# How to click on the extension button using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to verify the loaded extension in the firefox but the code is not working for me the html is attached and the xpath is `//*[@name="extension"]`

On firefox browser open url `about:addons`

html
Extensions

The firefox version is 77 and geckodriver 0.26.
I am getting exception element not found

Comment: Use name. it works for me or you can use cssSelector

Comment: Not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
 //Wait for element to be clickable
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("extension")));

    driver.findElement(By.name("extension")).click();
```

Comment: Tried with the wait but the solution is not working, it seems that not able to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WTtT.jpg) you have provided to click on the loaded extension you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the *element to be clickable* and can you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) and [python](/questions/tagged/python)

  ```
  # imports
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC        

  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.category[name='extension']>span[class='category-name'][data-l10n-id='addon-category-extension']"))).click()
  ```
- [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [java](/questions/tagged/java)

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='category' and @name='extension']/span[@class='category-name' and text()='Extensions']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: The issue is, not able to locate the element even though have waited 10 seconds to load the page. Tried testing it from the console also it fails to locate the element. Check the page about:addons.

Comment: @sourabhrawat Instead of asking the contributors to check the page, you need to update the question with as much as possible information you can provide, starting with text based relevant HTML. I know the issue but still I would like to see you asking the question right.

Comment: ..Thanks for your suggestion ..I have mentioned the URL in the comment as well and was not able to copy the html text that why I have put the screenshot of it..if you know the question then you should post only if you know the correct solution for it

Comment: Hi. The html can be copied with right click on the `body` element , then `Copy as outerHTML`. Posted solutions are OK. You should probably post the version number of Selenium, geckodriver and Firefox you use. Post also the error message you get.

Comment: Hey..not able to paste the html text coying it here.      <button is="category-button" viewid="addons://list/extension" class="category" role="tab" name="extension" aria-selected="true" data-l10n-id="addon-category-extension-title" tabindex="0" title="Extensions" selected=""><span class="category-name" data-l10n-id="addon-category-extension">Extensions</span></button>